# Error CS0119; class is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Upon becoming familiar with C#, I'm getting the following error when unit testing on the line where an assertion is made `Assert.IsInstanceTypeOf`.

`Error  CS0119  'Product' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

The matter of creating a type has been performed. What is causing this error to be raised?

**UnitTest1.cs**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using ProductNamespace;

namespace TestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestProduct
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestNewProduct()
        {
            Product mock_product = new Product(4.95);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mock_product, Product);
        }
    }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```
namespace ProductNamespace
{
    public class Product
    {
        private double price;

        public Product(double price)
        {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The matter of creating a type has been performed"?

Comment: I created a unit test project from scratch. After setting up the unit test, Visual Studio displayed a prompt to generate a new type. I was just conveying that I had done that.

Comment: Okay - it sounds like you thought this was related to the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the [`IsInstanceOfType(object, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isinstanceoftype?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_IsInstanceOfType_System_Object_System_Type_) method. To do that, you need to provide a `Type` argument, but currently you've just specified the class name directly. That's not a valid C# expression - you need to use the [`typeof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) to obtain a `Type` from the class name:

```cs
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mock_product, typeof(Product));
```

Note that this really isn't a useful test - you're not testing anything about the code, you're essentially asking whether .NET is behaving normally. If the code reaches that line (i.e. if the constructor doesn't throw an exception) then it's *bound* to pass - because the result of `new Xyz` is always an `Xyz`. (There's a slight edge case around COM interfaces, but it's not relevant here.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(mock_product, typeof(Product));
```

Please try the above. As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isinstanceoftype?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_IsInstanceOfType_System_Object_System_Type_), the second parameter should be of `Type`.